# Do any Mobile Ad providers tell you the keywords of the ad being displayed?

Tags: android, mobile, ads

Is there an ad-publishing SDK for mobile systems that can:
a) Tell me the ad keywords are for the currently displayed advert?
b) Request adverts about certain (other) keywords.

Here's the kind of thing I'd like to achieve code-wise:

```
nextAd = GetNextAdvert(listOfKeywords);

// Store keywords for adverts the user followed through with
nextAd.onClick(() => rememberKeyword = nextAd.keywords);
```